# Media Queries do CSS não funciona e esta conflitando

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, media-queries

Estou desenvolvendo o responsivo de uma página e a documentação do diz para fazer as *media queries* da seguinte maneira:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(max-width:992px){}
```

Uso Bootstrap 3.

**Portanto segue meu código CSS:**

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    /* de 0px até 767px */
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    /* de 768px até 992px*/

}
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    /* acima de 992px */
    .infos-schedule{
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .title-infos{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

.infos-schedule{
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.23;
    letter-spacing: 1.8px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #0a1414;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.title-infos{
    color: #037C74;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.create-in-schedule{
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.22;
    letter-spacing: 1.8px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #707070;
    display: block;
}
.title-header{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


.title{
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.24;
    letter-spacing: 2.1px;
    color: #0a1414;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card-schedules {
    margin: 10px 5px;
    background-color: #ecf3f8;
    height: 150px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-card class="card-schedules" 
                        *ngIf="pendente.status == 'Pendente'" >

                  <mat-card-content>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 title-header">
                      <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 infos-schedule padding0"><b class="title-infos">Anúncio: </b>{{ pendente.Anuncio }}</div>
                      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 create-in-schedule padding0">{{ pendente.created_in | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

O problema  é que a *media query* de `992px` não esta sendo obedecida nas classes já produzidas e predomina o CSS da *media query* maior.

Segue o que o Browser esta me mostrando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Já fiz até 
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    /* acima de 992px */
    .infos-schedule{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    .title-infos{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

Mas não altera...sempre está obedecendo o style já feito no css

Comment: Jovem, coloca o CSS completo se possível, só com esse pedaço de código não da pra entender direito o que está acontecendo, e coloca o HTML ai tb. E como te falei, da uma olhada nesse link, acredito que ele vai te esclarecer alguns pontos que podem te ajudar ai https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/media-queries-n%C3%A3o-funciona-medidas-informadas/351977#351977 Evite misturar min e max nos @media

Comment: Segue código completo

Comment: Cara além das coisa que já falamos me parece que seu CSS está inadequado. TODAS as regras @media devem ser as últimas coisas. Tipo primeiro vc escreve todo seu CSS, todas as classes etc, ai lá no final de tudo vc começa a escreve as media querys e coloca os @ madia que precisar, eles deve vir depois de tudo

Comment: Resposta editada. Mas vale considerar as ideias do @hugocsl... CSS é estilo em cascata. O que vem depois sobrescreve o que vem antes. Logo, as `@media` devem, também, seguir essa linha de hierarquia (herança)...

Comment: Cara, obrigado!! Eu mexi na ordem do CSS colocando as @media no final do código. Deu certo! não esperava que era isso, pois já trabalhei outras vezes começando no topo do código não tinha problema. Adotando nova prática haha Obrigado!

Comment: Também dei mole com isso, cara. Desculpe-me! Resposta editada. Ahh, sobre essa sobrescrita nas propriedades, no link que mencionei sobre `!important` tem uma explanação sobre. Tá bem explicadinho lá. Abração! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    /* de 0px até 767px */
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    /* de 768px até 992px*/
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
    /* acima de 992px */
    /* ... */
}
```

Lembrando que seu *HTML* precisa da *viewport*. Costumo utilizar nesta configuração:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=10, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

**@edit:**

Sobre a imagem postada na edição da pergunta, considere este meu comentário na resposta do @hugocsl:

> Dá pra colocar tudo com `max-width` ou `min-width` também, mas vai "manter" (herdar) as propriedades caso não sejam sobrescritas...

Como a própria nomenclatura diz, o CSS estiliza em cascata. Caso precise FORÇAR sobrescrita de algum atributo, adicione a palavra-chave `!important` ao lado do valor:

```
font-size: 15px !important;
```

Leitura recomendada: [SOpt - Para que serve a declaração “!important”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25311/para-que-serve-a-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-important)

**@edit2:**

Como o @hugocsl "nos lembrou", já que passou despercebido, você deve declarar as *media queries* depois dos elementos em questão.

> "*- TODAS as regras @media devem ser as últimas coisas. Tipo primeiro vc escreve todo seu CSS, todas as classes etc, ai lá no final de tudo vc começa a escreve as media querys e coloca os @ madia que precisar, eles deve vir depois de tudo*" – [hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl)

CSS estiliza em cascata, como o próprio nome já diz (*Cascading style sheet*). Sendo assim, seu código deve ficar assim:

```
.infos-schedule {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.23;
    letter-spacing: 1.8px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #0a1414;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.title-infos {
    color: #037C74;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* ... */

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    .infos-schedule{
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .title-infos{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

De tal forma que tudo que for declarado dentro da `@media` sobrescreva o que estiver declarado **antes dela**.

Comment: Vou responder com uma pergunta para mostrar imagens

Comment: @Cichoki Se o objetivo é implementar sua pergunta, utilize o botão "[editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/356923/edit)". Responda sua própria pergunta apenas se encontrou uma solução por si próprio e pretende compartilhá-la com a comunidade...

Comment: Feito ;) hahahaha

Comment: Valeu o crédito ✌

Comment: @hugocsl dalhe esforço pra ter uma resposta aceita sobre css lado à sua. (y) kkkk

Comment: Nada... as vezes eu saio na frente pq eu respondo antes, mas vc sempre está ai contribuindo! Fico feliz de ter mais gente respondendo com qualidade perguntas de CSS :)

Answer (score 5):

Cara seu problema é que o `min-width` sobrescreve o `max-width`

Veja aqui como está seu CSS

```
@media(min-width:768px){} /* aqui está "errado" */
@media(max-width:992px){...
```

Tudo que estiver dentro desse `@media(min-width:768px){}` vai sobrescrever o que estiver no `@media(max-width:992px){}`, pois as regras do `max-992` serão "anuladas" caso também estejam no `min-768`

Veja o que diz a documentação Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

> `max-width` overrides `width`, but `min-width` overrides `max-width`.

Uma solução é fazer como o @LipESprY disse na resposta dele. Ou então vc coloca os dois com `min-width`

```
@media(min-width:768px){} 
@media(min-width:992px){...
```

Essa resposta tem outros detalhes que vão te ajudar muito a entender esse conceito de `min` e `max` e os `@media` pq funciona e pq as vezes da problema:
 [Media Queries Não funciona Medidas Informadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/media-queries-n%C3%A3o-funciona-medidas-informadas/351977#351977)

Comment: Dá pra colocar tudo com `max-width` ou `min-width` também, mas vai "manter" (herdar) as propriedades caso não sejam sobrescritas... @off-topic: Com direito a menção honrosa! Hehe

Comment: Vou responder com uma pergunta para mostrar imagens

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- haha sim a sua resposta acho que é o melhor caminho pq tem menos chance de quebrar o código css que ele já tem eu acredito. Mas o ideal é seguir uma linha nos min - max, eu até acabei de incluir um link de outra resposta que tem umas explicações disso

Comment: @Cichoki NÃO use o campo de resposta para isso. Logo abaixo da sua pergunta original dem um link de EDITAR, clica nele e inclui a imagem etc, inclusive seria bom vc colocar o HTML e CSS completos

Comment: Feito ;) hahahaha