# @media entrando em conflito

Tags: html, css, front-end

Olá, gostaria de saber o motivo do por quê alguns comandos que pertencem a um `@media` específico, estarem influenciando e alterando o mesmo comando em um `@media` diferente. Por exemplo, quando coloco um "width: 30%" em alguma foto no `@media (min-width: 1200px)`, ele altera o tamanho dessa mesma foto também no `@media (min-width: 1500px)`. Descobri que em alguns casos, o problema é resolvido caso eu coloque um `!important` no elemento do `@media` afetado, mas isto nem sempre resolve. Estou organizando o *CSS* da seguinte forma:

- Desktops-1 (min-width: 1500px);
- Desktops-2 (min-width: 1200px); e
- Tablets-1 (min-width: 1000px).

Pretendo continuar colocando mais resoluções específicas para *responsivisar*, mas este *bug* está atrapalhando.

Comment: Vai depender dos seletores que usa e da ordem que aplica, sem ver o seu CSS e os seletores que esta usando não temos como responder, você deveria fornecer um exemplo PRONTO que possamos testar para podermos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Seu problema está explicado nessa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/media-queries-n%C3%A3o-funciona-medidas-informadas/351977#351977 na sua folha de CSS primeiro deve vir o 1000px, depois os estilos do 1200 e no final os do 1500 e assim por diante, no link tem mais detalhes

Comment: @hugocsl pode ser também, ou pode ser somente a ordem ou prioridade de seletores, não tem como afirmar nada, não tem código na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando min-width: por exemplo um aparelho com resolução de 1500px entrará em todas as validações anteriores, exemplo min-width: 700px, min-width: 1200px,etc.

Você pode arrumar isso de duas maneiras usar o max-width: 700px, e ir limitando por aparelho que contém a resolução até a resolução determinada.(Eu uso assim e dispenso o min-width).

Ou combinar as duas opções exemplo: `(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)` aí você garante aparelhos de resolução entre 768px a 979px(substitua pelos valores que melhor lhe atender)

Comment: obrigado, tentei aqui e deu certo